# PyDev Console not printing logging for all levels

Tags: python, eclipse, logging, pydev

I have average experience with python, btw i just installed eclipse and pydev on top of it. And strangely the behavior of logging module looks weird.

```
import datetime
import logging

print datetime.date.today()
print logging
logging.info("test")
print logging.info("test2")

--------
OUTPUT::
--------
2012-10-25
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
None
```

Any clue why logging.info din't work ?

btw not sure if this is related, but just after pydev installation import logging itself wasn't working. Then i checked python interpreter setting and logging module wasn't there in forced builtins list (Windows->preference->Pydev->Interpreter(python)->Forced Builtins). So i added that manually to make import logging work. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Because the default loglevel is `WARNING` and `logging.info()` logs at level lower than that. See the explanation [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example) and the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel).

To do what you want you could try this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('name_of_your_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info("Should get logged")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default level with `setLevel` before the first logging statement.

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if want to write into stdout:

```
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info('teste')
```

Output:

> teste